# Keep empty list in the same index, while flattening a list ot list (nested list)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of lists like this,

```
sm = [['123'],['456'],['789'],[],['101']]
```

then I flatten the list,

```
sm_flattened = [val for sublist in sm for val in sublist]
```

Now, I get this (`sm_flattened`),

```
['123', '456', '789', '101']
```

However, I need my `sm_flattened` like this,

```
['123', '456', '789', '', '101']
```

How can I get this? Any suggestions would be nice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do that, you'll need to transform your empty sublist in a sublist with an empty string inside.

One alternative would be:

`sm_flattened = [val for sublist in sm for val in (sublist or [''])]`

It basically uses `['']` instead of `sublist` in case `sublist` is empty for that iteration.